# 7-zip: How to open Add to Archive Dialog Box from command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, 7zip

I would like to open 7-Zip Add to archive dialog box from a command line. I believe it is a part of 7-zip file manager (**7zFM.ex**), but there is no help file.

I need something like:

```
C:\Program Files\7-Zip>7zFM.exe -dialog "C:\file-to-archive.txt"
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvIbU.png]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use -ad switch for 7zg.exe.

```
7zg.exe a k.7z -ad
```